# Return values in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am using Python 3.6

I have a list of dictionaries (below) and would like to return the following values: `id`, `name`, `color` for every record in my data. I cannot seem to figure out how to iterate through all the "pages" in my dataset to return all values. I have gotten as far as the `for` loop included below, but that only returns data for the first page and none of the others. The end-state I'm looking for would return the data in the structure I have in my `for` loop but for all pages.

My data and for loop:

```
mydict = [
  {
    "page": 1,
    "data":[
      {
        "id": 11111,
        "name": "smith",
        "color": "orange",
        "subsidiary": "no"
      },
      {
        "id": 22222,
        "name": "smith",
        "color": "orange",
        "subsidiary": "yes",
        "subsidiaries": [
          {
            "id": 33333,
            "name": "alpha",
            "color": "blue"
          },
          {
            "id": 44444,
            "name": "alpha",
            "color": "blue"
          }
    ],
    "last_updated": 123456789
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page": 2,
    "data":[
    {
      "id": 55555,
      "name": "smith",
      "color": "orange",
      "subsidiary": "no"
    },
    {
      "id": 66666,
      "name": "smith",
      "color": "orange",
      "subsidiary": "yes",
      "subsidiaries": [
        {
          "id": 77777,
          "name": "alpha",
          "color": "blue"
        },
        {
          "id": 88888,
          "name": "alpha",
          "color": "blue"
        }
  ],
  "last_updated": 987654321
    }
  ]
}
]

for i in mydict[0]['data']:
    print ({"cust_id": i['id'], "cust_name": i['name'], "fabric_color": i['color']})
```

Returns:

```
{'cust_id': 11111, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'}
{'cust_id': 22222, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary of lists. So you can use a nested `for` loop:

```
for d in mydict:
    for i in d['data']:
        print({"cust_id": i['id'], "cust_name": i['name'], "fabric_color": i['color']})
```

To store results in a list of dictionaries instead of just printing, you can append to a list:

```
L = []
for d in mydict:
    for i in d['data']:
        L.append({"cust_id": i['id'], "cust_name": i['name'], "fabric_color": i['color']})
```

More efficiently, you can use an equivalent list comprehension:

```
L = [{"cust_id": i['id'], "cust_name": i['name'], "fabric_color": i['color']} \
     for d in mydict for i in d['data']]

print(L)

[{'cust_id': 11111, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'},
 {'cust_id': 22222, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'},
 {'cust_id': 55555, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'},
 {'cust_id': 66666, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'}]
```

---

Here's an example which captures subsidiary data if it exists:

```
L = []
for d in mydict:
    for i in d['data']:
        L.append({"cust_id": i['id'], "cust_name": i['name'], "fabric_color": i['color']})
    if 'subsidiaries' in i:
        for s in i['subsidiaries']:
            L.append({"cust_id": s['id'], "cust_name": s['name'], "fabric_color": s['color']})

print(L)

[{'cust_id': 11111, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'},
 {'cust_id': 22222, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'},
 {'cust_id': 33333, 'cust_name': 'alpha', 'fabric_color': 'blue'},
 {'cust_id': 44444, 'cust_name': 'alpha', 'fabric_color': 'blue'},
 {'cust_id': 55555, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'},
 {'cust_id': 66666, 'cust_name': 'smith', 'fabric_color': 'orange'},
 {'cust_id': 77777, 'cust_name': 'alpha', 'fabric_color': 'blue'},
 {'cust_id': 88888, 'cust_name': 'alpha', 'fabric_color': 'blue'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! If you don't mind, how would I get the cust_id 33333 and 44444 with this method?

Comment: You will need a third nested loop to iterate the `subsidiaries`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
mydict = []
for page in mydict:
    print(page['page'])
    for data in page['data']:
        print ({"cust_id": data['id'], "cust_name": data['name'], "fabric_color":data['color']})
```

You were only iterating the first index of the dictionary when there are more than 1 element.